Are there examples of non-perfect graphs among these graphs
A graph $G$ is said to be perfect if $\chi(H)=\omega(H)$ hold for any
induced subgraph $H_i\subseteq G$ (and so for $G$ itself, too)
Start with a simple planar graph $H$ where every face is a 4-cycle. Let $H_s$ be the graph obtained by stellating every face of $H$, i.e., by inserting into every face of $H$ a new vertex that is adjacent to all vertices of the face.
We know that $H$ is a perfect graph (since any bipartite graph is  perfect), but is any $H_s$ a perfect graph? I hesitate to make a definitive statement, but I have checked a few examples, and it seems to hold.


The graph $H_s$ has clique number $3$ (since $H$ has clique number $2$, and a clique in $H_s$ cannot include more than one stellating vertex). It also has chromatic number $3$ (keep the $2$-coloring of $H$ and give all the stellating vertices a third color). So we can try to prove that $H_s$ is perfect directly from the definition: we can check that if $G_s$ is an induced subgraph of $H_s$, then the clique number $\omega(G_s)$ and the chromatic number $\chi(G_s)$ are equal.
Let $G_s$ be an induced subgraph of $H_s$, with $G$ the common subgraph of $G_s$ and $H$. If $G_s$ has no vertices, then $\omega(G_s)=\chi(G_s)=0$. Otherwise, if it has no edges, then $\omega(G_s)=\chi(G_s)=1$. If $G_s$ has both vertices and edges, then $2 \le \omega(G_s) \le \chi(G_s) \le 3$, and we can try to $2$-color $G_s$ by the following strategy:

Keep the $2$-coloring of $G$ that we know exists because $G$ is bipartite.
For each stellating vertex, try to give it a color not present on any of its neighbors.

If this strategy succeeds, then $\omega(G_s) = \chi(G_s) = 2$. If it fails, then there is a stellating vertex $x$ which has two neighbors of opposite colors. But then those two neighbors are consecutive vertices of the face that $x$ stellated - so, together with $x$, they form a triangle. In this case, $\omega(G_s) = \chi(G_s)=3$.
It follows that the stellated graph $H_s$ is guaranteed to be perfect.

I think that your proof is probably correct. However, I still have some confusion. Perhaps in a 3-coloring of a induced subgraph $G$, $H$  is not 2-colored but 3-colored. Based on this fundamental concern, I pose the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4934636/can-an-induced-subgraph-have-more-colors-in-the-minimum-coloring-of-its-supergra/4934644#4934644  to verify if my concern is valid.

That is, your discussion at the beginning might have assumed that all vertices of $H$ are 2-colored. It feels like some analysis was overlooked.

I thought of a slightly simpler proof. When I have time, I will try to add it.

Well, I think that something about my writeup should be cleared up, because "let $G$ be an induced subgraph of $G$" is incoherent - I'll edit in a moment. But we don't have the problem you're imagining. We are not considering some maliciously given coloring; I specifically said that we $3$-color $H_s$ by first $2$-coloring $H$, and then giving all the stellating vertices a third color.

I understand. Thank you. Indeed, $H_s$ has such a 3-coloring scheme in advance. Other coloring methods do not matter.
