Can an induced subgraph have more colors in the minimum coloring of its supergraph?
$G$ is a graph with chromatic number $k$. Its induced subgraph $H$ has chromatic number of $k-1$.  In any $k$-coloring of $G$, it is evident that $H$ uses at least $k-1$ colors, but can it use $k$ colors? I have a feeling that such graphs exist, but I haven't thought of any good examples yet.
Moreover, the more general question is as follows:
Let $G$ be a graph with chromatic number $\chi(G) $. Let $H$ be an induced subgraph of $G$. Find an example where $H$ uses more than $\chi(H)$ colors in a $\chi(G) $-coloring of $G$.

In any 2-coloring of the path $P_4$ the endpoints must have different colors.

Yes, it's possible in the stronger sense that sometimes $H$ has to use $k$ colours in every $k$-colouring of $G$. Here's an example:

This $G$ has a unique $3$-colouring (up to reordering colours), as shown. Taking $H$ to be the path of three vertices along the bottom, $H$ is $2$-chromatic but must use all three colours in any $3$-colouring of $G$.
